# Shared Library Discovery

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I am using C++ on Linux.  I want to dynamically bind a collection of unknown shared libraries.  I need my code to detect all the public functions exposed by the shared library and the string names of those functions.  How do I accomplish this task?

Comment: There is no point in binding this unknown set of functions: you can't call them (since you don't know what parameters they expect), so what are you going to do with the result of dlopen()?

Comment: So basically, you want to know how the "nm" utility works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no glibc function to enumerate all the public interface functions for a .so file. You can refer to libelf to read all symbols from a dynamic file. Libelf is here http://www.mr511.de/software/. After you find a symbol, you can use dlopen and dlsym to load it.